# How to hint the type of Django's model field `objects` to a dynamically generated class?

Tags: python, django, mypy

I have a `Team` model in my Django project. I create its custom model manager with [`QuerySet.as_manager()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager).

```
class TeamQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self) -> "models.QuerySet[Team]":
        return self.filter(is_active=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

    objects = TeamQuerySet.as_manager()
```

When I try to execute `Team.objects.active()`, mypy gives the following error:

```
error: "Manager[Any]" has no attribute "active"
```

```
In [5]: Team.objects
Out[5]: <django.db.models.manager.ManagerFromTeamQuerySet at 0x10eee1f70>
```

If I was explicitly defining a `TeamManager` class, there would be not a problem. How can I hint the type of Django model field `objects` to a dynamically generated class?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the `Manager[Any]` I assume you are already using [`django-stubs`](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs).

Unfortunately [it looks like there's an open issue to make `QuerySet.as_manager` generic over the model it's attached to](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/324) that has not been resolved yet.

Even if [the PR addressing the issue](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/pull/327) got merged I'm afraid it wouldn't address your immediate issue because the `as_manager` needs to be generic over the generic `QuerySet` subclass used to create the manager in order for both `.active` to be available and attributes relating to `Team` be available.

In this regard this [other PR](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/pull/290/), which is unfortunately quite stale, seems to properly address your issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explore this issue.

Comment: To add to the above you can work around this limitation by adding a `cast(TeamQuerySet[Team], ...)` around your `TeamQuerySet.as_manager()` call. Since the `Manager` generated by `as_manager` behaves 99% like the queryset it was created from it should cover your use case.

Comment: Finally, your annotation on `TeamQuerySet.active` is wrong as it's actually returning `TeamQuerySet[T]` where `T` is the generic. I think you can omit it and mypy will figure it out by itself.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I tried your suggestion, however I got the error `"TeamQuerySet" expects no type arguments, but 1 given`.

Comment: Not sure what's causing it. Maybe you need to make sure to extend `models.QuerySet['Team']` instead? And you'd only need a `cast(TeamQuerySet, TeamQuerySet.as_manager())`?

Comment: can someone put a good example on how to do the casting until its correctly fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around this with a little switch-a-roo for MyPy's sake:

```
_Q = TypeVar("_Q", bound="WorkflowQuerySet")


class WorkflowQuerySet(models.QuerySet["WorkflowModel"]):
    """
    Queryset for workflow objects.
    """

    def count_objects(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def latest_objects(self: _Q) -> _Q:
        raise NotImplementedError


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    # Create a type MyPy understands
    class WorkflowManager(models.Manager["WorkflowModel"]):
        def count_objects(self) -> int:
            ...

        def latest_objects(self) -> _Q:
            ...


else:
    WorkflowManager = WorkflowQuerySet.as_manager


class WorkflowModel(models.Model):
    """
    A model that has workflow.
    """

    objects = WorkflowManager()
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of work if you do that for every model

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer using generics and typevar

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from django.db import models

class BookQueryset(models.QuerySet['Book']):
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
   objects: BookQueryset = BookQueryset.as_manager()


book = Book.objects.all()[0]
```

If you inspect book is type Book

Comment: This gives the following error to me with mypy: `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "BookQueryset", base class "Model" defined the type as "BaseManager[Any]")`